# Data Source Update Mode in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm working in VB .NET and I like to use DataBindings, SqlDataAdapter, and DataTables.  The issue I'm having is that I can have the Data Source Update Mode set to Never on one form and the other form needs to have it set to at least OnPropertyChanged to be able to save the changes back to the database.  The issues arises when I try to save the data by calling...

```
BindingSource.EndEdit
adapter.Update(DataTable)
```

Why can controls on form1 be set to Never for update mode and save just fine while the other controls on form2 are set to never and not save at all?

Comment: The reason is somewhere you haven't shown us. If you want to modify the database why would you ever use `DataSourceUpdateMode.Never` ?

Comment: I wanted it only to update when I clicked a save button.  Sometimes it would automatically do it when you left the control.  That's when I would set it to Never and it would save when I called EndEdit and Update.